# How was induction used here?

Tags: induction

I was reading the proof of the induction for this question and didn't understand the step where they did $t! > (n^2)^{t-n^2} = n^tn^{t-n^2} > n^t$. How is $n^2$ even related to the problem and if so how is the inequality even true?

**Problem and solution**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First notice that $(2n^2)!>(n^2)^{n^2}$. This is because
$$
(2n^2)! = 1\cdot 2\cdot \dots \cdot n^2 \cdot (n^2+1) \cdot \dots \cdot 2n^2,
$$

and there are $n^2$ factors after the $(n^2+1)$ factor (including).

Now when $t>2n^2$ we have
$$
t! = 1\cdot 2\cdot \dots \cdot n^2 \cdot (n^2+1) \cdot \dots \cdot 2n^2 \cdot \dots \cdot t,
$$

and there are $(t-n^2)$ factors after the $(n^2+1)$ factor (including).

In effect $t! > (n^2)^{t-n^2}$.